# Setting column width in HTML table

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

Currently, I have a table that looks like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Submitted</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Revisions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nov. 22, 2011, 2:14 a.m.</td>
        <td><a href="/essays/edit/6">Hello</a></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need the `Title` column to be as wide as possible while the other columns are **just enough** to contain their content. I also need the table to fill its container (100% width).
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a quick and dirty hack, but you can simply use the following CSS:

```css
td, th {
    white-space: nowrap; /* to prevent splitting content into several lines */
}
th:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

There is no way that cells inside table can exceed its overall width, so it may work.

Alternatively you can use JavaScript to calculate middle column width dynamically or set fixed cells width.

Comment: It makes the other columns too narrow and push the content into next lines. Doesn't look good.

Comment: You can always set "min-width" in CSS or "white-space: nowrap;" to prevent pusing content into next lines.

Comment: putting "white-space: nowrap;" on the first row won't help the rest. Putting it in every row violates DRY. I feel that min-width won't work well either because the column width may changes across browsers and tables. I'm looking for a universal solution across all tables.

Comment: DRY is violated if you use something like that: 

    td:nth-of-type(1) {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    td:nth-of-type(3) {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

You are picky, lol. The solution I mentioned works for me.